# RtlStringCbPrintf is not in ntstrsafe.h as described

Tags: c++, string, unicode-string, windows-kernel, strsafe

I am trying to use **RtlStringCbPrintf** with Winsock Kernel.  I have included Ntstrsafe.h but the compiler gives me the error

```
Error 4 error C3861: 'RtlStringCbPrintf': identifier not found  c:\bw\epic_sl\musslcomm\musslcomm\commmessenger\socketx.h   124 1   CommMessenger
```

If I use **RtlStringCbPrintfA** or **RtlStringCbPrintfW** then it does compile.  Why can't I use the generic version?  Looking in Ntstrsafe.h I see prototype declarations of **RtlStringCbPrintfA** and **RtlStringCbPrintfW** but no declaration for **RtlStringCbPrintf** although the comments refer to it.  Why can't I use the generic form so that my Character Set property selects which version to use?  My Character Set property  is set to **Use Multi-Byte Character Set**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because windows does not provide RtlStringCbPrintf define for this two functions. From msdn:

> Use RtlStringCbPrintfW to handle Unicode strings and
>   RtlStringCbPrintfA to handle ANSI strings. The form you use depends on
>   your data..

The example from msdn use RtlStringCbPrintfW() function, not RtlStringCbPrintf().

You can define RtlStringCbPrintf() yourself:

```
#if defined(UNICODE)
# define RtlStringCbPrintf RtlStringCbPrintfA
#else
# define RtlStringCbPrintf RtlStringCbPrintfW
#endif
```

Comment: Okay, however the documentation is confusing.  It shows the syntax for a function that is doesn't actually exist. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562824%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 

In other cases where there multiple forms the syntax box shows each of them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx